# Computer Browser service not unstalled and not installable

Tags: windows, deployment

I'm faced with a Windows 2003 server that doesn't have the Computer Browser service, and I have no idea how to get it back.  The Server has "Run Advertised Programs" in the control panel, so that indicates SMS (MS Systems Management Server) may have been used to lock down the server.  But we don't have SMS (we've ingerited this server from another organisation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been able to add it back by adding "Client for Microsoft Windows".   Sorry,SMS was just a red herring

Answer (score 0):

Run the Services applet (or right-click "My Computer" and choose "Manage", then click Services). I don't think that service can be uninstalled, so it must simply be stopped.

Comment: No, thanks, but as I found, the "Client for Microsoft Windows" has to be installed for the Computer Browser service to be there

Answer (score 0):

The service can be checked just by sending query.  Below is the syntax.  The alias name is 'browser'.

(1) Open cmd type sc query browser - enter.  This will show the status of service.

(2) sc config browser start= auto

(3) sc config browser start= manual

(4) sc config browser start= disable

(5) sc start browser

(6) net start browser

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1Lrxap5OjbCUoZMl8VM00Q